# Symfony where to initialize routes? (routing.yml or inside controller)

Tags: php, html, symfony

On the [routing page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) of smyfony is an routing example (the first one). Now they give us 4 options of code (Annotations, YAML, XML, PHP). Where is the difference? And maybe you can take a look on my `Controller + Route`.

The controller looks like this:

```
<?php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

    class ToDoListController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/ToDoList", name="ToDoList")
         */

        public function showToDoList()
        {

        }
    }
?>
```

Now I added this route into the `routing.yml` too.

```
ToDoList:
    path: /Aufgabenliste
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle\Controller  \ToDoListController::showToDoList}
```

Is that correct? Whats about the path? In the first example of the symfony page they wrote `defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:show }` but in the description they wrote:

> The _controller string is called the logical name. It follows a pattern that points to a specific PHP class and method, in this case the AppBundle\Controller\BlogController::listAction and AppBundle\Controller\BlogController::showAction methods.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/routing.html#loading-routes

Comment: @keyboardSmasher thanks! I Is my entry inside the `routing.yml` correct? My `ToDoListController` is locadet in `\src\AppBundle\Controller\ToDoListController.php`

Comment: With annotations you just have to point to each bundle's Controller directory and Symfony will automatically load all of your annotation routes. You should just copy/paste the code at the link I provided above.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher ah okay. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright. So in Symfony you get to choose between different methods of routing. You can do this for example via annotations or yml(I used to use yml but now I switched to annotations). The only difference is in... format of the file ;) For example I realy like to use annotations because instead of having one billion entries in one file I have every route right next to the code it leads to. At this point for you it depends on what you like better. However I think it's considered as good practice to use annotations.

```
<?php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

    class ToDoListController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/ToDoList", name="ToDoList")
         */
         public function showToDoList()
         {

         }
    }  
?>
```

Code above is ok - you used required namespaces and created correct annotation. All of this you have to do in your bundle you are working on. Also you have to go to app/config/routing.yml and put there something like this:

```
YourBundleName:
    resource: "@YouBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Of course it's just an  example - you need to adjust it to your needs. This way you are saying to Symfony that you want to use annotations.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the explanation about the different formats.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you have more questions just let me know.